# Написать функцию, которая проверяет, упорядочены ли элементы списка по алфавиту С++

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) 
{

    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    string word;
    int i;
    vector<string> v;
    cout << "Сколько слов хотите ввести -"<<endl;
    while (!(cin >> i) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))
    {
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "Введено недопустимое значение. Повторите попытку." << endl;
    }
    while (i != 0)
    {
        cout << "Введите слово - " << endl;
        cin >> word;
            v.push_back(word);
            i--;
    }
    bool result;

    vector<string>::iterator iter = v.begin();
    vector<string>::iterator iter_end = v.end();

    cout << "Введённые слова: ";
    for (; iter != iter_end; iter++)
        cout << *iter << " ";

    cout << endl;

    result = is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end());

    if (result == true)
        cout << "Элементы отсортированы" << endl;
    if (result == false)
        cout << "Элементы не отсортированы" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос как раз не ясен. Что вы понимаете под списком? Покажите код, что у вас в нем не получается.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow код добавил.Не получается сортировка точнее не понимаю как её правильно сделать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Специально для этого сделана [функция](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) в `<algorithm>`

Comment: Я бы конечно предложил дополнить примером кода, но так, как автор вопроса ленится добавить код, то  - каков вопрос, таков ответ.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hK0NE7q5
Я только не могу придумать как вывести в консоль output.txt
Ну или вообще не записывать отсортированное в файл и сразу вывести

Comment: @mia я так и не понял как работает эта функция и как ёё применять.объясните дурному

Answer (score 1):

Допустим список в вашем случае это массив символов тогда самое прямое и простое как пробка решение выглядит так:

```
bool isSorted(const string& str)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (str[i - 1] > str[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```